# how to view data from database with static images in php

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to view multiple data from database my static images are also showing multiple time. I try to use `foreach` and while with `i++` but both time I get the same result. 
How to view one image but multiple data.

[image: Image show how data is viewing now]

```
  <div class="row">
  <?php 
                // set array
    $array = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    { 
            // add each row returned into an array
      $array[] = $row;   
  }
  // debug:
  foreach ($array as $arrays)
  {
    ?>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-1.png" alt="">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['address']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/call.png" alt="">
                <h3>Mobile </h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['mobile_no']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-2.png" alt="">
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['phone_no'];?> </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-3.png" alt="">
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['email']; ?></h4>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So you only want the image showing as a header for all the data right?

Comment: @priya can you also show that how exactly you want your result be shown, because it can be achieve by multiple approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal because your images are in the foreach.

Remove your first `foreach`

Make function like

```
foreach($array as $value){

echo $value;

}
```

and put them below your images.

example with your code : (but better make functions for all the `foreach`)

```
<div class="row">
  <?php 
                // set array
    $array = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    { 
            // add each row returned into an array
      $array[] = $row;   
  }
  // debug:

    ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-1.png" alt="">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <h4><?php  foreach ($array as $arrays)
  {

  echo $arrays['mobile_no'];


  }?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/call.png" alt="">
                <h3>Mobile </h3>
                <h4>//same here</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-2.png" alt="">
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <h4>//same here </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-3.png" alt="">
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <h4>//same here</h4>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the Image field outside the loop:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php 
                // set array
    $array = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    { 
            // add each row returned into an array
      $array[] = $row;   
  }
  // debug:
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-1.png" alt="">
                <h3>Address</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/call.png" alt="">
                <h3>Mobile </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-2.png" alt="">
                <h3>Phone</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-3.png" alt="">
                <h3>Email</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
  foreach ($array as $arrays)
  {
    ?>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item text-center">

                <h4><?php echo $arrays['address']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item text-center">

                <h4><?php echo $arrays['mobile_no']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item text-center">

                <h4><?php echo $arrays['phone_no'];?> </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item text-center">

                <h4><?php echo $arrays['email']; ?></h4>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest put not the most beatiful solution is to just check if its your "header" line and adding those images at first run.. you can also add the if around your images instead of dublication to much. but you will get the idea

```
  <div class="row">
  <?php 
                // set array
    $array = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
    { 
            // add each row returned into an array
      $array[] = $row;   
  }
  // debug:
$i = 0;
  foreach ($array as $arrays)
  {
    ?>
        if($i == 0){
        //first line
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-1.png" alt="">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['address']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/call.png" alt="">
                <h3>Mobile </h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['mobile_no']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-2.png" alt="">
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['phone_no'];?> </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <img src="img/soul-icon/address-3.png" alt="">
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['email']; ?></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        }else{
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <h3>Address</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['address']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">
                <h3>Mobile </h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['mobile_no']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">                  
                <h3>Phone</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['phone_no'];?> </h4>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="address_item">                    
                <h3>Email</h3>
                <h4><?php echo $arrays['email']; ?></h4>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```